# Clear search bar text when - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am using a search bar in my application. On search bar keypad there is search button. On tapping of search button older text of search bar removed. When search button is pressed this method call:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

I want to clear search bar text, I have tried with this code:

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
     searchBar.text = nil; 
     //searchBar is object of UISearchBar
}
```

I have already set the delegate for search bar, `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` method also called when search button is pressed. But it does not clear the searchbar text.

Please any one suggest me how can i do that?

Comment: Try using searchBar.text = @"";

Comment: Nup, not working searchBar.text = @""

Comment: Is the program control entering in this delegate method??

Comment: please specify program control, within -(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar method i added delegate of search bar  with this code   [searchbar setDelegate: self]; also i am not able to resign keypad when this method call.

Comment: It means that your program control is not entering in this method. Have you specified <UISearchBarDelegate> in your .h file???

Comment: Put a break-point in this method and check if this method gets called or not?

Comment: I have already added this method on my .h file @interface AddToCartScreen : UIViewController<UISearchBarDelegate>

Comment: Have you put the break-point and then run your program?

Comment: i have already put break point on this method. method is called but search bar text is not cleared.

Comment: Then i think your search bar doesn't have memory,check for it..as this code is working fine in my case.

Comment: maybe you need self.searchBar.delegate = self;